# PHP Grouping an Array with Multiple Dimensions from database results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, multidimensional-array

I have an array as a result of a database query. Lines include two dimensions and some metrics. 
Metrics must be summed by dimension groups.

Here is an example raw data array in table view:
[image]

Here is the exact array:

```
array(13) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["source_name"]=>
    string(8) "A"
    ["week"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["picks"]=>
    int(1)
    ["won"]=>
    int(0)
    ["lost"]=>
    int(1)
    ["draw"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["source_name"]=>
    string(8) "A"
    ["week"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["picks"]=>
    int(1)
    ["won"]=>
    int(1)
    ["lost"]=>
    int(0)
    ["draw"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(6) {
    ["source_name"]=>
    string(8) "A"
    ["week"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["picks"]=>
    int(1)
    ["won"]=>
    int(1)
    ["lost"]=>
    int(0)
    ["draw"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(6) {
    ["source_name"]=>
    string(8) "A"
    ["week"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["picks"]=>
    int(1)
    ["won"]=>
    int(1)
    ["lost"]=>
    int(0)
    ["draw"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(6) {
    ["source_name"]=>
    string(8) "A"
    ["week"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["picks"]=>
    int(1)
    ["won"]=>
    int(0)
    ["lost"]=>
    int(1)
    ["draw"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(6) {
    ["source_name"]=>
    string(8) "A"
    ["week"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["picks"]=>
    int(1)
    ["won"]=>
    int(0)
    ["lost"]=>
    int(1)
    ["draw"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(6) {
    ["source_name"]=>
    string(8) "A"
    ["week"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["picks"]=>
    int(1)
    ["won"]=>
    int(1)
    ["lost"]=>
    int(0)
    ["draw"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [7]=>
  array(6) {
    ["source_name"]=>
    string(7) "B"
    ["week"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["picks"]=>
    int(1)
    ["won"]=>
    int(0)
    ["lost"]=>
    int(1)
    ["draw"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [8]=>
  array(6) {
    ["source_name"]=>
    string(7) "B"
    ["week"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["picks"]=>
    int(1)
    ["won"]=>
    int(1)
    ["lost"]=>
    int(0)
    ["draw"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [9]=>
  array(6) {
    ["source_name"]=>
    string(7) "B"
    ["week"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["picks"]=>
    int(1)
    ["won"]=>
    int(0)
    ["lost"]=>
    int(1)
    ["draw"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [10]=>
  array(6) {
    ["source_name"]=>
    string(7) "B"
    ["week"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["picks"]=>
    int(1)
    ["won"]=>
    int(1)
    ["lost"]=>
    int(0)
    ["draw"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [11]=>
  array(6) {
    ["source_name"]=>
    string(9) "C"
    ["week"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["picks"]=>
    int(1)
    ["won"]=>
    int(1)
    ["lost"]=>
    int(0)
    ["draw"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [12]=>
  array(6) {
    ["source_name"]=>
    string(9) "C"
    ["week"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["picks"]=>
    int(1)
    ["won"]=>
    int(1)
    ["lost"]=>
    int(0)
    ["draw"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

Here is what I expect to get as output:
[image]

What is the best way to get that output?

Thanks.

Comment: So, loop over the array and sum the values into a new array. It's not clear to me where you are stuck.

Comment: Is this array a result of a database query?

Comment: @CodeGodie actually I couldn't figure out how can I group and sum without multiple loop. And, yes, it's a result of a database query.

Comment: @GolezTrol I haven't figure out how to make unique dimension sets and sum metrics with that groupings.

Comment: Why does it have to be done without multiple loops? Also, if it's a database query result, why not add the grouping to the query? Databases are good at that stuff and it saves in the amount of data that has to be sent from the database to PHP.

Comment: I agree with @GolezTrol you need to focus on your database query rather than iterating through the results. Sql queries can reproduce what you want by using COUNT GROUP_BY ORDER_BY, etc...

Comment: @GolezTrol I make some calculation after I got result from database. They're a bit complicated queries for me. So, maybe, my next betterment can be this. Great suggesstion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do `foreach` over here like as

```
$result = [];
foreach($data as $key => $value){
    $hash = $value['source_name'] ."_". $value['week'];

    if(isset($result[$hash])){
         $result[$hash]['picks'] += $value['picks'];
         $result[$hash]['won'] += $value['won'];
         $result[$hash]['lost'] += $value['lost'];
         $result[$hash]['draw'] += $value['draw'];
    }else{
         $result[$hash] = $value;
    }
}
print_r(array_values($result));
```

Comment: I don't understand what is happening in that else branch... Shouldn't that be `$result[$hash] = $value;`?

Comment: OMG! I didn't seen that I've updated my answer @GolezTrol. Thanks for pointing out I just posted answer and closed the window

Comment: @GolezTrol Even I'm thinking why it's not been downvoted

Comment: I have stopped to sum week numbers, and that was what I want!

Removed this line: $result[$hash]['week'] += $value['week'];

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh yes I'm in so much hurry that I didn't seen my answer

Comment: Even though your answer explains how to obtain the desired output iterating through the array, it does not fully solve the problem at hand. OP should not be iterating through these random database results, instead his database query should be improved so that the right results are obtained.

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned this array is a result of a database query. Thus, you should not be iterating through the results like this, your focus should be in how you are obtaining these results from your database as SQL can do all this math for you with better performance.

To show you this, imagine your database table is named `my_table` and has all the information you posted above: (`source_name`, `week`, `picks`, `won`, `lost`, `draw`) :

```
+-------------+------+-------+-----+------+------+
| source_name | week | picks | won | lost | draw |
+-------------+------+-------+-----+------+------+
| A           | 10   | 1     | 0   | 1    | 0    |
+-------------+------+-------+-----+------+------+
| A           | 10   | 1     | 1   | 0    | 0    |
+-------------+------+-------+-----+------+------+
| A           | 11   | 1     | 1   | 0    | 0    |
+-------------+------+-------+-----+------+------+
| A           | 11   | 1     | 1   | 0    | 0    |
+-------------+------+-------+-----+------+------+
| A           | 11   | 1     | 0   | 1    | 0    |
+-------------+------+-------+-----+------+------+
| A           | 11   | 1     | 0   | 1    | 0    |
+-------------+------+-------+-----+------+------+
| A           | 11   | 1     | 1   | 0    | 0    |
+-------------+------+-------+-----+------+------+
| B           | 10   | 1     | 0   | 1    | 0    |
+-------------+------+-------+-----+------+------+
| B           | 10   | 1     | 1   | 0    | 0    |
+-------------+------+-------+-----+------+------+
| B           | 11   | 1     | 0   | 1    | 0    |
+-------------+------+-------+-----+------+------+
| B           | 11   | 1     | 1   | 0    | 0    |
+-------------+------+-------+-----+------+------+
| C           | 11   | 1     | 1   | 0    | 0    |
+-------------+------+-------+-----+------+------+
| C           | 11   | 1     | 1   | 0    | 0    |
+-------------+------+-------+-----+------+------+
```

If you run the following SQL query, you will get your desired results without you having to worry about iterating or looping later.

```
SELECT source_name, week, sum(picks), sum(won), sum(lost), sum(draw)
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY source_name, week 
ORDER BY source_name
```

RESULT:

```
+-------------+------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| source_name | week | sum(picks) | sum(won) | sum(lost) | sum(draw) |
+-------------+------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| A           | 10   | 2          | 1        | 1         | 0         |
+-------------+------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| A           | 11   | 5          | 3        | 2         | 0         |
+-------------+------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| B           | 10   | 2          | 1        | 1         | 0         |
+-------------+------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| B           | 11   | 2          | 1        | 1         | 0         |
+-------------+------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| C           | 11   | 2          | 2        | 0         | 0         |
+-------------+------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Check out this **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d389b3/13)** to help you understand it.